# Pandas dataframe returns incorrect sort using two float columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am playing with some geo data.  Given a point, I am trying to map to an object.  So for each connection, I generate two distances, both floats.  To find the closest, I want to sort my dataframe by both distances and pick the top row.

Unfortunately when I run a sort (`df.sort_values(by=['direct distance', 'pt_to_candidate']`) I get the following out-of-order result

[image]

I would expect the top two rows, but flipped.  If I run the sort on either column solo, I get expected results.  If I flip the order of the sort (`['pt_to_candidate', 'direct distance']`)  I get a correct, though not what I necessarily want for my function.

Both columns are type float64.

Why is this sort returning oddly?

For completeness, I should state that I have more columns and rows.  From the main dataframe, I filter first and then sort.  Also, I cannot recreate by manually entering data into a new dataframe, so I suspect the float length is the issue.

**Edit**
Adding a value_counts on 'direct distance'

```
4.246947    7
3.147303    2
2.875081    1
2.875081    1
```

Comment: Can you try: `df.sort_values(by=['direct distance', 'pt_to_candidate'])`  (just changed placement of parenthesis and square brackets)

Comment: Probably the first number is very slightly smaller than the second.  Please edit your question to include `df["direct distance"].values.tolist()`.  (Also, please post text and not images; images can't be copy/pasted.)

Comment: It seems weird result. I think your direct distance column values varies by floating digits, try rounding up the values in that column and try the same,

Comment: @ChrisA sorry, that was a typo in the question, updated

Comment: @DSM brilliant idea.  It looks like you're onto something, they are _slightly_ different!

Comment: What are your data types? (`df.dtypes`)

Comment: @DSM you deserve the credit here.  If I round my floats to four decimal places, I get the sort order I expect.